# Maximizing the value of an integral in an unknown $h(x)$

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, maxima-minima, calculus-of-variations

I'm an undergraduate student and I've only studied Riemann integrals in detail so far. When I was trying to solve this question, I tried to make use of the boundedness of $h(x)$ but that only works in the interval $[0,1]$, and that helps me find the minimum in that region not the maximum. Then, I tried to think of a function that may satisfy all of these conditions (like a sine wave whose wavelength was adjusted to satisfy the last condition), but I couldn't even find any common continuous function that would satisfy all 4 conditions; one of the zero conditions always got left out. So could someone please help me find such a function, and also give me a direction to proceed to rigorously show what the maximum of this definite integral will be (possibly using elementary techniques)?

> Compute $\max \int_{-1} ^1 x^3 h(x) \ dx $ where $h(x)$ is any continuous function on the interval $-1 \leq x \leq 1$ subject to the restrictions
> \begin{align*} \int_{-1}^1 h(x) \ dx = \int_{-1}^1 xh(x) \ dx = \int_{-1}^1 x^2 h(x) \ dx &= 0; \\
> \int_{-1}^1 |h(x)|^2 \ dx &= 1.
> \end{align*}

Comment: Can you share your full attempt in the post? This appears to be more of a variational calculus problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality for integrals.

The Cauchy-Schwarz inequality for integrals states that:
$$\left(\int f(x)g(x)\,dx\right)^2 \leq \int f^2(x)\,dx \cdot \int g^2(x)\, dx
$$

If we plug in $f(x) = x^3$ and $g(x) = h(x)$, then we get:

$$ I^2 \le \int_{-1}^1 (x^3)^2 dx \cdot \int_{-1}^1 h^2(x) dx = \frac{2}{7} \cdot 1 = \frac{2}{7}$$

This implies that the integral is bound by the inequality

$$ I \le \sqrt{\frac{2}{7}}$$

Comment: Looks like you didn’t use the first constraint (that string of equalities ending with $=0$). How are you sure the answer won’t change when you take that into account?

Comment: @Divide1918 If you apply Cauchy Schwarz for every integral, you will see that all inequalities are all satisfied, since 0 is less than any positive real number.

Comment: Wait, what, it's that simple?

Comment: @Cognoscenti Do you have the answer with you? We can confirm it if you want. Errare human est, I may be wrong. The longer way would be to consider the Hilbert space of powers of $x$ and applying the Gram-Schmidt process.

Comment: I don't have the answer actually, it's an unsolved worksheet problem but I guess it makes sense

Comment: Do you have any kind of example of a function in mind which would satisfy all these conditions?

Comment: @Cognoscenti Hunting for $h(x)$ would be unnecessary. There are many possible functions that satisfy $h(x)$; we have to find the maximum possible value of the integral of $x^3h(x)$ from $-1$ to $1$. Even if we are able to construct a specific $h(x)$, it does not necessitate that it will have the maximum value of the required integral.

Comment: Got it, thanks!